# filter query_posts using a meta_key that is an array

Tags: php, wordpress

Inside one of my custom post types, I have a custom field that gets its values from another custom post type, and show them in a dropdown menu, something that's called a Relation Custom Field in PODS.

When you select one of the items of the dropdown menu, then display it, it returns an array.

What I need to do is to filter the posts inside this CPT through the value of one of the custom field array keys.

```
$industry = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'industry', true);
var_dump($industry);
```

Result:

```
array(37) {
  ["ID"]=>
  string(2) "94"
  ["post_author"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["post_date"]=>
  string(19) "2014-05-20 18:30:28"
  ...
}
```

I need to filter this post through the `industry`'s ID value.
What I've tried to do is to modify the `$args` of the `query_posts()`:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'industries_contacts',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => 'industry',
      'value' => array('ID' => $industry_ID),
      'compare' => '='
    )
  ),
  'posts_per_page'   => 10, 
  'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
);
query_posts($args);
```

But of course this failed to work, and gave me an error.

Please keep in mind that I want to use WordPress' pagination, so I can't run conditional statements inside the loop to remove the unwanted posts from the archive page.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in an array containing your value under the key of 'ID' rather than passing in the value of the key 'ID' in your `$industry_ID` variable. This should be `$industry_ID['ID']` instead.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'industries_contacts',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => 'industry',
      // you want to pass in the ID element of the $industry_ID array.
      'value' => $industry_ID['ID'],
      'compare' => '='
    )
  ),
  'posts_per_page'   => 10, 
  'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
);
query_posts($args);
```